# Google-Fabric daily summary mail is not received

Tags: google-fabric

We are receiving daily summary notification.

Receiving daily summary notifications is enabled.

However, there is a day when the daily summary notification mail is not received.

Daily summary email is not received daily?

Comment: Fabric summary emails stopped for my projects on Jan 12th 2018. They still haven't started back up. Are some accounts still impacted?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for letting me know. We are aware of an issue that prevented these from being sent last week. This issue is now resolved. Thanks!